# $.connection.hub.userId undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I am new to SignalR and went through a sample implementation. I created a simple Hub, and so far what I'm trying to accomplish is to send a message to a specific user. I got it to work for a day, but it's not longer working. I have checked the CustomUserIdProvider and it's actually returning the correct user Id. Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

This is my hub

```cs
public class AssignmentHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
}
```

This is my CustomerUserIdProvider

```cs
public class CustomUserIdProvider: IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        var userId = ((ClaimsIdentity) HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        return userId;
    }
}
```

These are my scripts from the _Layout.cshtml

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var assignmentNotificator = $.connection.assignmentHub;

        assignmentNotificator.client.addNotification = function (message) {   
            alert(message);
        }

        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            console.log($.connection.hub.userId);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And part of my Global.asax

```cs
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => new CustomUserIdProvider());
    }
```

Comment: If you are looking for a way to uniquely identify your users, you can use the connectionid, or you can create a new group for each user and broadcast your message to the groupid.

Comment: ConnectionId by design refers to tabs. Each tabs gets a new Id. Groups I use them in a different manner, like grouping users per department per say. The CustomUserIdProvider is the recommended approach. I got it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Fowler has confirmed there’s no built-in userId. Then removing from the _Layout the line with `$.connection.hub.userId` fix the problem. I’d say since there’s no built-in userId having that line invalidates the mapping created in the CustomUserIdProvider.